# Should a question involving proper use of terms be asked in the meta section?

Tags: discussion

I have some doubts about [a question](https://askubuntu.com/q/261532/47206) on the correct use of terminology when talking about video players.

So, it may seem that it is about "how to ask a question" and be seen as improper in the main area of the site and more suited for meta.

But I think that it is about a matter of fact (**what** is the 'engine' etc), not a meta question (not about the website). Am I right? May I keep the question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your question is about "What is the engine" then yes, it is fine for the main site. However, your question(s) tend to be a bit vague (extensive details with many sub-questions are confusing, and not a good fit for this site), and so it is not easy to just answer "The Question".

If you have a question about terminology, then Meta is a better place to ask. Remember however, that any questions you ask on the main site must be related to Ubuntu or using Ubuntu, and any questions asked on Meta must be about the site or using the site. If in doubt, always take a look at the FAQs for the [Main Site](https://askubuntu.com/faq) and for [Meta](https://meta.askubuntu.com/faq).